# send smtp email to multiple receivers

Tags: go

I am using [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jpillora/cb46d183eca0710d909a/raw/19c524ccaa1f4003feb0a63bc77477486601eb43/smtp-gmail-send.go) to send `smtp`. It works for one receiver but I'd like to have multiple receivers. I have tried the following:

```
func sendemail(body string) {  
    from := "smtpemail" 
    pass := "pass"
    to := "a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com"
    ....
}
```

I have also tried:

```
to := "\"a@gmail.com\",\"b@gmail.com\""
```

and:

```
to := []string{"a@gmail.com","b@gmail.com"}
```

None of them work. Sorry it is so simple, I just begin to work with `golang`.

Comment: The latest form (using slice) should work. What was the error message returned by [`smtp.SendMail`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#SendMail)?

Comment: line 15: invalid operation: ("From: " + from + string("\nTo: ")) + to (mismatched types string and []string)  and for line 17: cannot use to (type []string) as type string in array or slice literal

Comment: You can't concat `string` with `[]string` simply by `+` operator. Quick solution will be replacing `... + to` with `strings.Join(to, ",")`. Don't forget to import `strings` package.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the `net/smtp` docs:

> The msg parameter should be an RFC 822-style email with headers first,
>   a blank line, and then the message body. The lines of msg should be
>   CRLF terminated. The msg headers should usually include fields such as
>   "From", "To", "Subject", and "Cc".

[RFC 822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html) requires `To:` header value to be a comma separated list. So while the `to` variable should remain a `[]string` and be passed to `smtp.SendMail` as its `to` parameter, the mail header (in the message) should have it as a comma separated list. Try below to see if it works:

```
func send(body string) {
    // ...
    to := []string{"foo@mailinator.com", "bar@mailinator.com"}
    toHeader := strings.Join(to, ",")

    msg := "From: " + from + "\n" +
        "To: " + toHeader + "\n" + // use toHeader
        "Subject: Hello there\n\n" +
        body

    err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.gmail.com:587",
        smtp.PlainAuth("", from, pass, "smtp.gmail.com"),
        from, to, []byte(msg))

    // ...
}
```